# Assembly Langugage

Tags: assembly, operating-system

Why **Assembly Language is different in Mac and window** . AS I read that Mac and Window are using same processors (Intel based)? (And Assembly language is machine dependent and using same Intel processor but having different Assembly language code).

Comment: What differences are you referring to? If the Mac computer and the Windows computer use the same processor, they have the same instruction set. There may be syntax differences for the assemblers for those machines however.

Comment: There are portable x86 assemblers like NASM and GAS that you can use on Windows or Mac (or Linux), or that you can use to make Windows executables from a Mac, or whatever.  Same language, same syntax, although the code you'd write in that language might differ at least slightly because of ABI differences.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Assembly language is defined by the assembler, the software that reads the file.  The machine code is defined by the processor, the assembler just has to output the right machine code for the input assembly language.